# Should I initialize a cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this code:

```
mapx.create(image.size(), CV_32FC1);
mapy.create(image.size(), CV_32FC1);
```

what is the values in the mapx and mapy after this? Are all data is zero?

what about this type of initialization:

```
  cv::Mat  mapx(image.size(), CV_32FC1);
```

Do I need explicitly set the value of each element to zero?

How can I set the value of each element to say -1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data after `create` should be undefined. In fact, your are just allocating memory.

```
cv::Mat  mapx(image.size(), CV_32FC1);
```

is exactly as

```
cv::Mat1f mapx(image.size());
```

and

```
cv::Mat mapy;
mapy.create(image.size(), CV_32FC1);
```

You can assign an initial value (e.g. -1) like this:

```
cv::Mat1f(images.size(), -1.f);
```

Regarding you main question **Should I initialize a cv::Mat**, the answer is that in general you don't need to. From OpenCV doc:

Instead of writing:

```
Mat color;
...
Mat gray(color.rows, color.cols, color.depth());
cvtColor(color, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

you can simply write:

```
Mat color;
...
Mat gray;
cvtColor(color, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the opencv documentation :

```
Mat::zeros
Mat::ones
Mat A = Mat::ones(100, 100, CV_8U)*3; // make 100x100 matrix filled with 3.
```

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-zeros

How can I set the value of each element to say -1?

I think something like that :

```
Mat A = Mat::ones(100, 100, CV_8U)*-1; // make 100x100 matrix filled with -1.
```

Comment: thanks. If I am not using this approach, what would be the value of each element in map? Is it unknown or zero or .. ?